# React-Spring is not animating

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

So I am trying to animate a container with an background image and some text. I have set a config of duration and  opacity of 0 to an opacity of 1 but the component loads normally. I do have the component as part of a private route. Its the page that displays after loggin in.

```
              to= {{opacity:1, marginTop:0 }}
              config = {{delay:4000, duration:4000}}>
        {(props) => (

            
          <div style={props}>
             <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${cancer})`}} className="container-img"> 
              <h2> What is Cancer?</h2>

              <p className="paragraph">
                The dogmatic view of cancer has been around for a long time.
                This view is called the Somatic Mutation Theory. This Theory is
                believed that cancer arises from damaged DNA in the cells that
                causes out of ccontrol growth.
              </p>
              <p className="paragraph">
                New Evidence shows that Cancer is caused by the damage to the
                mitochondria causing the cells to fall back on ancient pathways
                of fermentation. Cancer cells ferment Glucose and/or Glutamine
                for energy or ATP.
              </p>

              <p className="paragraph">
                If Cancer is a genetic disease, then why when they did a
                scientic experiment in the 1960's where they took the
                mitochondria of a cancer cell and put it in a normal cell the
                cell turned cancerous. This theory is called the Metabolic
                Theory of Cancer.
              </p>
            </div>
           </div> 
        )}
      </Spring>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing SpringValues to a regular dom element:

```
<div style={props}>
```

What you want to be doing is passing them to an `animated` element:

```
// import { animated } from 'react-spring'

<animated.div style={props}>
```

As described in the [docs](https://react-spring.io/basics#finally-tie-the-animated-values-to-your-view)